# Is there a way to indicate a tab in the opposite direction?

Tags: java, coding-style

Ok, the question might sound weird at first, but is there a shortcut to indicate a tab in the opposite direction? Shortcut would mean something like:

```
\t
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. Flagged as NARQ

Comment: there is no tab in opposite direction. where did you see something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't such a thing.

`\t` corresponds to ASCII 9 (horizontal tab). There isn't a "reverse horizontal tab" in ASCII. The closest is a series of ASCII 8 characters (backspace).

Answer (score 15):

If you mean the opposite of pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key in an editor, then you're looking for <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Are there any popular workarounds that i could use?

Comment: @user1420042 That... doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Oh, I noticed this is tagged [coding-style](/questions/tagged/coding-style) and I noticed you said it was right-aligned. Go to the line you want to reverse-tab and try this: <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

### Original post

I think you need the [Right to Left Override](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm). This will make all text backwards, so when you use a tab it will indent in the opposite direction.

Your question doesn't really make sense, though. How could you indent to the left? Put one less `\t` entity? Example:

```
//Original
String s = "\t\t\tText";
//Indented to left
String s = "\t\tText";
```

Comment: no, i am looking for a way to indent to the left.

Comment: well, if your text is aligned to the right

Comment: @user1420042 In what? A `JTextArea`?

Comment: @user1420042 are you writing code in Microsoft Word, or some other editor that supports text formatting? Because the only alignment of plain text is left-aligned, so your question simply does not make sense.

Comment: @user1420042 Oh, wait I completely misunderstood your question. See edit